# Applying Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm studying for a grad-school preliminary exam, and came across this problem which I am unable to solve.

---

Let $C$ be a closed curve in the plane $ax + by + cz = 0$ (where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ are not all zero $0$), enclosing a region with area $S$.  Evaluate 
$$ I:= \oint\limits_C \left| \begin{array}{ccc} 
dx & dy & dz \\
a  & b  & c  \\
x  & y  & z \end{array} \right|
$$

where the integral along $C$ is counterclockwise relative to the normal direction $(a,b,c)$ to the plane.

---

Expanding the determinant yields $$
I = \oint\limits_C (bz - cy)dx + (cx - az)dy + (ay - bx)dz. $$

If we call $\Omega$ the region bounded by $C$, an application of Green's Theorem (or Stokes Theorem, if you prefer) yields $$
I = 2\iint\limits_\Omega a dydz + bdzdx + c dxdy.
$$

From here, I'm not sure what to do; I suspect that it's a simple solution and that I've just forgotten my vector calculus.  Anyway, any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT: Substitute in $z = \frac{1}{c}\left(-ax - by \right)$ and then applying Green's Theorem doesn't bring me any closer.  Making such a substitution yields $$ I = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{c} \iint_\Omega dxdy $$

If $c \neq 0$ as required to make such a substitution, it is not the case that $\iint dxdy = S$.

---

SECOND EDIT:  I've solved the problem, making use of the following version of Stokes' theorem: $$ \iint_\Omega (\nabla \times \mathbf{F} ) \cdot \mathbf{n} dS = \oint_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}. $$

The above can be written as \begin{align*} I &= \oint\limits_C (bz - cy,cx - az,ay - bx)\cdot d\mathbf{r} \\
&= \iint_\Omega (\nabla \times (bz - cy,cx - az,ay - bx)) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}(a,b,c)\right) dS  \\
&=\iint_\Omega (2a,2b,2c) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}(a,b,c)\right) dS  \\
&=  2 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \iint_\Omega dS  \\
&= 2\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} (\text{Area of } \Omega) \end{align*}

Comment: To start, try writing down the volume element on the plane.

Comment: What is Green's Theorem?

Comment: @anomaly, I think that's my problem, is that I'm having trouble parameterizing the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Use the plane equation as

$$ ax + by + cz = 0  \implies z = -\frac{a}{c}x -\frac{b}{c}y  \implies dz= -\frac{a}{c}dx - \frac{b}{c}dy $$

and substitute for $z$ and $dz$ in the integral

$$ \oint\limits_C (bz - cy)dx + (cx - az)dy + (ay - bx)dz. $$

Then Green's theorem is straightforward.

Comment: Making such a substitution yields $I = \frac{1}{c}\oint_C (-(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)ydx + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)x dy = \frac{2}{c} \iint (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) dxdy = \frac{2}{c}(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)S$.  My intuition tells me that this isn't correct, due to the lack of symmetry; why do we have a $1/c$ in the front rather than a $1/a$ or a $1/b$?

Comment: I think the problem is that $dxdy$ isn't the area element of the plane, and I'm not sure how to fix that.